# MBA 13 2017 High Sierra. External LaCie 1TB SSD Time machine added, partition grayed out

Tags: disk-utility, partition, ssd

After loading TimeMachine I decided to partition the SSD; via Disk Utility the partition button is grayed out. I erased the SSD to start again but partition button remained grayed out.
How do I partition the SSD now?

Comment: The first problem was that in the 'erase' section there was no option for selecting a scheme (no Box existed).

Comment: The first problem, David, was that in the 'erase' section there was no option for selecting a scheme (no Box existed). Diskutil list shows internal SSD as having GUID partition scheme; external SSD as FDisk partition scheme. So how to covert the external disk to GUID partition?

Answer (score 1):

The Disk Utility application can partition the external drive, if you use GUID Partition Map scheme. Also, you need to create a one or more temporary `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` partitions in order keep the partition button from being grayed out.

Below is an example of how to create two `MS-DOS (FAT)` partitions using a 16 GB flash drive.

1. Erase the drive.

   [image: e1]
2. Partition the drive.

   [image: E2]
3. Erase the first partition.

   [image: e3]

The results are shown below.

[image: e10]

[image: e11]

[image: e12]